# Pass values from 1st datagridview to another datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, selectedvalue

So this is the code

```
DataTable Getselectedrows(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Item Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Price");

        foreach(DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
        {
            if(column.Visible)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add();
            }
        }

        object[] cellval = new object[dgv.Columns.Count];
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            if (!row.Selected) continue;
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
                cellval[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;

            dt.Rows.Add(cellval);
        }
        return dt; 
    }
```

and i call it in my add button

```
        dataGridView3.DataSource = Getselectedrows(dataGridView2);
```

This is the result, i can only pass the first selected value in the first datagridview on the first row in the 2nd datagridview, but when i select another value from the first datagrid and add it, it just change the value on the first row in second datagrid.. Help guys

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding another row, you are replacing whole DataSource using this code `dataGridView3.DataSource = Getselectedrows(dataGridView2);`

Comment: oh i see. im sorry to that. but how will i do it? how will i add another row if iclick the add button?

Comment: hmm, you can do something like this:

`foreach(DataRow row in Getselectedrows(dataGridView2))
{
   dataGridView3.Rows.Add(row.Copy());
}`
but you have to check if row exists in dataGridView3, I think...